# Can I still get Facebook Friends with An App Created BEFORE April 30 2014?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know about the whole April 30 policy of big brother doom that Facebook has introduced, but I read this somewhere:

> "For apps which were active before April 30th, these apps can call
>   either Graph API v2.0 or Graph API v1.0, but Graph API v1.0 will be
>   deprecated on April 30th 2015."

Does this mean that if I have an app active before April 30th 2014, that I am still able to use API v1.0 to get all the users friends until next year?

I also have read that it depends if the user logs into the app with API1.0 or API2.0 ... How do users have the ability to choose the API, and does this mean that I will have access to some user's friends if they use V1.0, but not if they use V2.0?

Comment: If your app was active before 4/30/2014 you are able to use API v1.0 until 4/30/2015. In API v1.0 /me/friends return all friends

Comment: [Facebook has clarified](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) that after April 30, 2015 apps using the v1 APIs will get the v2 behavior. Note that this means your app may work, but there are potential compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Apps created before April 30th 2014 can still get all friends, until April 30th 2015.

You can force older Apps to use a newer API version:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1

(see the "version" parameter in the init-function)

You can also add the version tag in an API call, see changelog for more information about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Keep in mind that you can´t force a new App to use an older version of the API.